# c++ Export project to exe

Tags: c++

Im using Visual Studio 2015 and want to export my project which only includes the .cpp file and a .wav file which supposed to be played. How do i export the exe including the .wav file

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
# include <winuser.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main()
{
    FreeConsole();
    while (1)
    {
        for (char button = 0; button < 256; button++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(button) & 0x8000)
            {
                PlaySound(TEXT("dab.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
            }
        }
        Sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "export" in this context.

Comment: if you compile your .cpp, vs will give you a .exe file but you can't compile .wav file. You have to keep your .exe and your .wav file. Can't mix the two files

Comment: Embedding resources into an executable is not part of C++ - it is specific to particular host systems.   To get more useful answers, you would be better off tagging the question as windows rather than C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your `.wav` file as resource of your project.
see documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fc1e5by.aspx

Then you can play your sound from resource id.
see documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743679(v=vs.85).aspx